# Display data from API Database with FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api, search

```
export class Diet extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

          data: [],
      fullData: [],
      loading: false,
      error: null,
      query: "",
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {

      this.requestAPIFood();
  }

  requestAPIFood = _.debounce(() => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    const apiURL =
      "https://api.edamam.com/api/food-database/v2/nutrients?app_id=${########}&app_key=${#######}";
    fetch(apiURL)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((resJson) => {
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          data: resJson,
          fullData: resJson,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({ error, loading: false });
      });
  }, 250);

  renderFooter = () => {
    if (!this.state.loading) return null;
    return (
      <View
        style={{ paddingVertical: 20, borderTopWidth: 1, borderColor: "red" }}
      >
        <ActivityIndicator animating size="large" />
      </View>
    );
  };

  _renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={{ height: hp("5%") }}>
        <Text style={{ left: wp("1%") }}>{item.food}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  handleSearch = (text) => {
    const data = _.filter(this.state.fullData);
    this.setState({ data, query: text });
  };

  render() {

     return (

         <SearchBar
            placeholder="Search Food..."
            onChangeText={this.handleSearch}
            value={data}
          />
            <List >
              <FlatList
                data={this.state.data}
                renderItem={this._renderItem}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
              />
            </List>
```

Good evening, I'm working on a `SearchBar` component to search food from the API database of Edamam (this is the link to the documentation: https://developer.edamam.com/food-database-api-docs) and display the result on a `FlatList` as you can see above, but when I start typing nothing will appear and I really can't seem to find the error.

Comment: What is inside `SearchBar` component? Are you using `e.target.value` somewhere to read entered value in text input?

Comment: No, I'm not. I used this method by watching a tutorial, and it worked fine with the Database the teacher was using, but when I inserted the Edamam database (changed the link) it stopped working

Comment: If your problem is "Search bar is not working". You should show the minimal code of `SearchBar` component as well. or are you using this component: https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/searchbar.html ?

Comment: If you changed the API, then most probably data format of response is also changed. You need to take care of that as well if you want it to wok as it did in tuorial.